# Chrome Extension not working after Chrome 73 but only if loaded from the store

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apsic-xbench-extension-fo/nhadbgflnognogbicnbeepnbpehlocgc) that suddenly stopped working right after the Chrome 73 update.

The symptom is that if I go to the page where the extension is designed to work (https://translate.google.com/toolkit) and I click on the extension icon, instead of running the background page code, the pop-up menu for the extension appears (as if I had right-clicked the icon).

However, if I load the exact same code locally (not from the store), the Chrome extension runs fine.

The background page console for the extension loaded from the store does not seem to issue any error.  If I place a breakpoint for the first line in the onClicked listener for the page action, it does not stop there for the Chrome store extension (and the breakpoint works fine for the extension loaded locally).

Why do I get different behaviors if I load the extension from the Chrome store or I load it locally?

In Chrome 72, the extension worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Answering own question: I tracked down the issue.  It turned out that if the Chrome extension was installed from the Chrome store using Chrome 72, then it did not work right after the update to Chrome 73.

However, if after Chrome 73 is updated, you remove the extension and add it again from the Chrome store, then the Chrome extension works again. Strange but true.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 73 inject some new security. Just try to move your xHTTP requests to your background script with `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and get response with `SendResponse` callback.

In content or popup script replace ajax with :

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
  { action: "check", data: {/* params for url */}}, 
  // callback with url response
  function(response) {
    if( response.success ) {
      var myDataFromUrl = response.data;
      ...
    } else {
      console.log('Error with `check`,', response.data);
    }
  }
);
```

From background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var url = 'https://mysyte.com/';
    if(request.action === 'check' ) {
      url = url + 'check'
      ajax( url, request.data, 
        success: function( d ) {
          sendResponse({success: true, data: d});
        },
        error : function( d ) {
          sendResponse({success: false, data: d});
        }
      );
    }
});

function ajax( url, params, cbSuccess, cbError ) { ... }
```